# conditional random file picker

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been trying to make this feature on wordpress for a while.
The idea is simply as this, i want to have a form and based on answers, the website will give you a random photo/video from a directory (Could be cloud directory, or WP storage). but the conditional randomness is where i'm stuck.

if your answers are x,y you will get a random .jpg or .png file from directory
if your answers are z,r you will get a random .mp4 or .mov filr from directory

how could i put it conditional and random at the same time?

used WPForm to collect answers, WPForm should automatically direct user to another page where they should find the file

Comment: First, you need to find how to redirect the user after **WPForm** submission,  Then you need to find how you can read input from **WPForm** submission then after that you if/else and random value things will be applied. all of these requires a good knowledge of php, WordPress, WP hooks and core knowledge of **WPForm** plugin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.